# C# Multidimensional array with string[] and string

Tags: c#, multidimensional-array

I basically want to make an array which contains one string[] and one normal string.

onion / {strawberry, banana, grape} in one array.

```
string[,] foodArray = new string[,] { onion, { strawberry, banana, grape } }
```

I'm wondering if it's even possible...

Thank you.

Comment: Only if you're willing to have it be an array of `object` and check / cast appropriately to either `string` or `string[]`.

Comment: Generally you'd use a `struct` or a class for that, why do you need an array?

Comment: If the single string should be unique or can be considered as something like a key you might aim for a Dictionary<string, string[]>.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you do not really want a two dimensional array in this case.
What you really want is an array of a tuple.

```
using System;

namespace tuple_array
{
    using Item = Tuple<String,String[]>;
    
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Item[] foodarray = new Item[] {
                new Item("onion", new string[]
                             { "strawberry", "banana", "grape" })
            };
            foreach (var item in foodarray) {
                var (f,fs) = item;
                var foo = string.Join(",", fs);
                Console.WriteLine($"[{f},[{foo}]]");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

It looks somewhat clumsy in C#, the F# version is much more terse and pretty:

```ml
type A = (string * string []) []
let a : A = [| "onion", [| "strawberry"; "banana"; "grape" |] |]
printfn "%A" a
```

Comment: Thank you! Getting to know Tuple was really helpful!

Answer (score 3):

This sort of data typing is unclear for what you want to do. Use your types to clearly communicate your intentions

If you plan to lookup by the first string, I might recommend `Dictionary<string, List<string>>`. The Dictionary collection is an extremely useful collection type

If you want strictly arrays then you must use a [jagged array](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/arrays/jagged-arrays) as this will allow you to constrain the first "column" to being only 1 length while the list (2nd column) may be variable length. This would mean `string[][] foodArray = new string[1][];`

In either case multidimensionals arrays are *not* suited here, it will lead to wasted space as it allocates all the cells for the dimensions you set. Rule of thumb, always prefer jagged over multidimensional arrays unless you are absolutely sure the entire multidimensional array will be filled to its max in *all* its dimensions.

Comment: Thank you! I only now learned what jagged array is.